# How to input special alphabets of diffrent languages to HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a Multi language website, everything works fine, the problem is that it can not recognise some special alphabets of diffrent languages in just some tags.

for example for a word in French like (fonctionnalités ) it would changed to (fonctionnalit&#233;s) 
all happened in Html so it seems I need some changes in my HTMLS.
all the pages are inherited from _Layout.Cshtml

the problem exist in this line of Layout

```
<meta property="og:description" content="@ViewBag.desc" />
```

Appreciate any Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is encoded, that's why, you can use `HTML.Raw(ViewBag.desc)` to prevent the razor page from encoding the string.

Comment: thank you very much. it seems completely helpful. but let me try it and then accept . thank you very much

Comment: sorry I have a question, if I use Html.Raw then does it increase the risk of XSS attacks or not?

Comment: you should worry about that when the user post the data, I would ensure that user input is encoded before it is submitted to the database.